# When are static properties initialised in testing in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a class with an optional type property (static). I set this when I start to use the class. Obviously, when the program first starts, the property has no value.

My question is about testing. I expected the class to be initialised at the start of every test (i.e. the type property set back to having no value). However, it seems the class is initiated once at the beginning of all my tests and therefore the type property has the same value in all tests, which is not what I want.

What are the rules about class initialisation in testing? Is there any way I can force my class to "reset"?

Thanks,

Julian

Comment: Swift's static and class properties are atomically initialized upon first use of the type they're in. For info on setting up and tearing down context for your test cases, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, static properties on your test case are persistent throughout all your tests. However, `XCTestCase` has two sets of methods that you can override to customize this, called `setUp()` and `tearDown()`. It's somewhat confusing, since there are identically named class and instance methods for each of these; override the class methods to have something happen only once, and override the instance methods to make something happen before or after each individual test. In your case, it would probably make the most sense to override the instance method version of `setUp()` and have it reset your properties.

Comment: Thanks for that very clear answer. I have added code to the setup to reset my static property.